# Debugging dpkg configure failure with grub

Tags: grub2, dpkg

On one of my machines dpkg is unable to finish installing/configuring grub, only giving the error message:

> subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255

Full output:

```
# dpkg --configure grub-pc
Setting up grub-pc (1.99-27+deb7u3) ...
device node not found
device node not found
device node not found
device node not found
Installation finished. No error reported.
Installation finished. No error reported.
dpkg: error processing grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
```

There is nothing in the log files that would shed any more light.

Running dpkg with some debug options reveals a little more:

```
# dpkg -D10113 --configure grub-pc
Setting up grub-pc (1.99-27+deb7u3) ...
D000002: fork/exec /var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.postinst ( configure  )
device node not found
device node not found
device node not found
device node not found
Installation finished. No error reported.
Installation finished. No error reported.
dpkg: error processing grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
D010000: trigproc_run_deferred
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
```

Now I know the problem is someplace in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.postinst configure`, but that script doesn't seem to have any verbosity or debug options and is just to large to read through with nearly 700 lines. The script also doesn't have any `exit 255` calls, so I tend to believe the problem isn't even in there but in some other script that is called.

The configure task also fails for the kernel processes:

```
# dpkg --configure linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
Setting up linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 (3.16.39-1+deb8u1~bpo70+1) ...
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
 (/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64.postinst line 263.
initrd.img(/boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
) points to /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
 (/boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64.postinst line 263.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 255
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64.postinst line 634.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
```

Line `634` in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64.postinst` boils down to this command:

```
run-parts --report --exit-on-error --arg=3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 --arg=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 /etc/kernel/postinst.d
```

Running this command manually results in:

```
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 255
```

This script is, as far as I can tell, only a wrapper that does a check and then calls `update-grub`, which works without error.

`update-grub` just runs `grub-mkconfig`, so I ran this command and checked the return value:

```
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64
# echo $?
255
```

This seems to be the culprit. The script works, finds all kernels, generates a valid grub config (saves it as `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new` though) and then exits with return code 255. And of course it doesn't have any debug options.

How can I go on debugging the problem?

Additional information that might or might not be helpful:

- the system is running debian wheezy
- GRUB is version 1.99-27+deb7u3
- the system has an mdraid
- the system has been running for years, it's not a new installation. The error appeared only recently
- not quite sure, but I believe the error started to appear after a faulty hard drive was replaced
- the configure task only fails for grub and the kernel packages. All other packages can be installed without error

*More information from questions that came up later*

```
zulu668:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md2 : active raid1 sda4[2] sdb4[1]
      1456504640 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sda3[2] sdb3[1]
      7996352 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda2[2] sdb2[1]
      499392 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
zulu668:~# sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Wed Oct 29 12:40:33 2014
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 499392 (487.77 MiB 511.38 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 499392 (487.77 MiB 511.38 MB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Wed Mar 15 14:51:01 2017
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : zulu668:0  (local to host zulu668)
           UUID : 22e14818:7754cf01:67287402:c31a3328
         Events : 217

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       2       8        2        0      active sync   /dev/sda2
       1       8       18        1      active sync   /dev/sdb2
```

Comment: Ideas: Run `strace` on the skripts. Lots of output you'll have to wade through, but you can see what's happening, and the `device node not found` errors are worth investigating. Rename `grub-mkconfig` and replace with a script that calls the renamed version and then does `exit 0`, and see if it now works. If yes, have a closer look at it.

Comment: strace is a good idea, but this is its only output: `[-] Error 0x7a911401 in attaching to process!`

Comment: Any  own parameters set in /etc/default/grub ?

Comment: @Bahamut no, I didn't touch the file.

Comment: `fdisk -l 2>/dev/null | egrep "Disk /|/dev/" | sed "s#^/dev/#Part /dev/#" | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/://' | xargs -n1 -IX sudo sh -c "hexdump -v -s 0x80 -n  2 -e '2/1 \"%x\" \"\\n\"' X | xargs -n1 -IY sh -c \"case  \"Y\" in '48b4') echo X: GRUB 2 v1.96 ;; 'aa75' | '5272') echo X: GRUB Legacy ;; '7c3c') echo X: GRUB 2 v1.97 oder v1.98 ;; '020') echo X: GRUB 2 v1.99 ;; *) echo X: Kein GRUB Y ;; esac\"" `

Comment: @Bahamut the result of your command is `GRUB 2 v1.99` for both sda and sdb and "No GRUB" for all other devices

Comment: Maybe stupid idea, `cat /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig | grep mv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, at the time of writing, you brilliantly narrowed down your problem to `grub-mkconfig` and wonder how to debug it.

`grub-mkconfig` is a shell script that basically build your `grub.cfg` configuration file by executing every script in `/etc/grub.d`. There is a `set -e` command at the beginning of `grub-mkconfig`, meaning "stop at the first non-managed error you encounter". Chances are your problem is due to the failure of one of the grub.d scripts.

First, let's identify the culprit. Run:

```
dash -vx grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

`dash`, the Bourne Shell interpreter that is most likely bound to `/bin/sh`, will output every line it executes. Since the script probably fails due to the `set -e` command, the last line is likely to be the grub.d sub-script that fails. I assume you will get something like:

```
+ echo ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/99_buggy_script ###
+ /etc/grub.d/99_buggy_script
```

The script name itself won't probably give you enough evidence on what is going on. Since it's also a Bourne shell script, you can debug it the same way. Change the first line of the grub.d script from

```
#!/bin/sh
```

To:

```
#!/bin/sh -vx
```

And run `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` (`dash -vx` is no longer necessary). The trace you will get is from the grub.d script.

Hopefully, the problem will be obvious now. Once you have fixed it, don't forget to remove the `-vx` flags at the beginning of the grub.d sub-script.

Comment: I'm not at the end yet, but this really helped me to make progress

Comment: Glad to read it. Do not hesitate to update your question and leave a comment here if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

I read that you should install `grub` on all harddrives belonging to a raid. Since you replaced a faulty hdd you might check that by running:

```
dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
```

when comming to the `GRUB install devices` section, you may see which devices are marked by an asterisk `*` and which aren't, and you can mark them using the cursor and space key/s. (All primary devids `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc` etc. should be marked)

Finishing this step should reinstall grub and bring all back to normal.

Comment: I already did that. multiple times.

Comment: To be more specific: The command you propose doesn't work at all due to my problem: `/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: grub-pc is broken or not fully installed`. But I alrady purged and reinstalled grub a couple of times, and the config you describe is done during the (re)installation. Grub is installed on all physical discs.

Comment: did you run `sudo grub-mkdevicemap; sudo update-grub` ?

Comment: Yes, both of them. I also checked the resulting `/boot/grub/device.map`, the devices are correct.

Comment: did you check your raid, all ok? `cat /proc/mdstat` and `sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0`

Comment: Yes. I added the output to the question, as it is too large for a comment.